# Why is the Mean of the 1st Principal Components 0?

Tags: regression, pca

I am reading a text on principal components which has the following excerpt:

> Since $\frac1n \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij} =0$, the sample mean of the first principal component scores, $\bar{z}_1$, equals $0$.

The book also mentions:

> $$Z_1 =\phi_{11}X_1+\phi_{21}X_2+\ldots+\phi_{p1}X_p$$

I don't understand how the standardization of the predictor variables mandates that the mean of the first principal component scores also be 0. What am I missing? I think part of the challenge is that they didn't provide the exact mathematical formulation of $\bar{z}_1$. What exactly is $\bar{z}_1$?

Comment: Suppose every data (row) vector $x$ satisfies a set of linear equations $xA=0$ for a fixed matrix $A.$  Since PCs are linear combinations $\omega x$ (for various $\omega,$ one per PC), notice that $(\omega x)A = \omega (xA)=\omega(0)=0,$ too.  In other words: *the set of solutions of a set of linear equations is a vector subspace.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PCA creates new variables $Z$ based on linear combinations of the old variables $X$.  It is assumed that $X_1, \cdots, X_p$ have been centered (and scaled).  In other words, for $j=1,\cdots,p$, $\sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij} = 0$.  Let the first principal component equal
\begin{eqnarray*}
z_{1i} = \sum_{j=1}^p \phi_{j1} x_{ij}
\end{eqnarray*}
The textbook means that $\bar{z}_1$ equals
\begin{eqnarray*}
\bar{z}_1 &=& \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n z_{1i} \\
&=& \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^p \phi_{j1} x_{ij} \\
&=& \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^p \phi_{j1} \sum_{i=1}^n  x_{ij} \\
&=& 0.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I have used PCA before bur never thought of this point before. I will come back to this answer in a few months when I need to use it again. Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

If the $X_i$'s are zero mean a linear combination of them will also have zero mean. Am I missunderstanging your question?